# Filter out metadata fields and only return source fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to tell elasticsearch to not return any metadata? Currently I can select which fields I want to be returned in source. But I only want fields in source. I would prefer to not have the metadata returned as I dont need it and would save some unnecessary parsing and transport etc.

I found [Elasticsearch - how to return only data, not meta information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860588/elasticsearch-how-to-return-only-data-not-meta-information) older question where somebody commented that it wasnt possible to do it then. Wondering if this functionality has been added or is still missing?

Comment: As far as I know, this functionality _still_ does not exist. However, you can create a plugin to do this [as shown here](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-just-source/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/examples/justsource/rest/action/RestJustSourceAction.java).

Comment: thanks! wondering why ES doesn't have this functionality. Maybe just doesn't have a priority high enough.

Comment: I suppose that some things could become quite difficult without the metadata, particularly paging.

Comment: but that information doesn't need to be provided to the end user necessarily.

Answer (score 37):

[response_filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering)

> All REST APIs accept a **filter_path** parameter that can be used to
>   reduce the response returned by elasticsearch. This parameter takes a
>   comma separated list of filters expressed with the dot notation:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&filter_path=took,hits.hits._id,hits.hits._score'
{
  "took" : 3,
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "3640",
        "_score" : 1.0
      },
      {
        "_id" : "3642",
        "_score" : 1.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In python

```
def get_all( connection, index_name, type_name ):

    query = {
        "match_all":{}
    }

    result = connection.search( index_name, type_name,
             {"query": query},
             filter_path= ["took", "hits.hits._id", "hits.hits.score"])

    return result
```

> If you want to filter _source fields, you should consider combining
>   the already existing 
>   **_source** parameter (see Get API for more details)
>   with the filter_path parameter like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source&_source=title'
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [ {
      "_source":{"title":"Book #2"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"title":"Book #1"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"title":"Book #3"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's not that difficult if we know it :)

```
http://localhost:9200/***{index_name}***/***{type}***/_search?pretty&filter_path=took,hits.hits._id,hits.hits._score,**hits.hits._source**
```

Comment: http://localhost:9200/{index_name}/{type}/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source

Answer (score 4):

I do not know options like this in a query. It is possible to do this in a get by Id request.

```
/{index}/{type}/{id}/_source
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#_source

Comment: yep, i had seen that.

Answer (score 1):

`filter_path` (response filtering) doesn't have any effect for the version 1.5 of elasticsearch.

Unless the option had a different name or was moved in the documentation, it was first added in [version 1.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/common-options.html#_response_filtering).