# Retrieve only _source from elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way so that I get only the data present in _source of my Document & not any other metadata like _index,_type,_id,_score while retrieving it from Index?

Comment: take a look at here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283033/filter-out-metadata-fields-and-only-return-source-fields-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it how to do it.

```
GET /<index>/<type>/<id>/_source
```

will return only `_source` field.

Example:
Create a document with `ID 123`

```
PUT /website/blog/123
{
  "title": "My first blog entry",
  "text":  "Just trying this out...",
  "date":  "2014/01/01"
}
```

To Retrieve just the `_source` field

```
GET /website/blog/123/_source
```

returned:

```
{
  "title": "My first blog entry",
  "text":  "Just trying this out...",
  "date":  "2014/01/01"
}
```

Comment: how to do this in mongoosastic or npm elasticsearch module ??