# Elasticsearch: get only _source field with a search query (not providing document id)

Tags: elasticsearch

I've two documents stored in an elasticsearch index,

```
Index: employee

document#1
{
  "name": "praveen"
  "job": "developer"
  "company": "foo"
}

document#2
{
  "name": "joey"
  "job": "manager"
  "company": "bar"
}
```

To fetch just the `company` field, I'm querying the index like,

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/employee/_search?pretty&q=name:praveen&filter_path=hits.hits._source.company"
```

And it returns with following,

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "company" : "foo"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Question:** Can i get just the value of `_source` field without everything else? So that the response looks like following,

```
{
  "company": "foo"
}
```

Is it possible in Elasticsearch?

PS: This question isn't a duplicate of [Retrieve only _source from elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573431/retrieve-only-source-from-elasticsearch) because I am querying the whole index using `search` api rather than fetching a particular document using its `ID`.

I am aware of `_source` endpoint (that is used in above SO question) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#_source but I think it works only with a document `ID` and doesn't work for a search.

Comment: Nope, `hits.hits._source` will always be there

Comment: hmm, I kind of expecting this answer but wanted to make sure I'm not missing something. Thanks for your response @Val. If you want to answer to this, I'll accept that.

Comment: You can eventually pipe the call to ES into `jq` to do the job: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774728/4604579

Comment: Perfect, just tried jq in a batch script and it works really well. Thanks very much @Val! please post an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I did that, Thank you.