# remove metadata from response hits.hits

Tags: elasticsearch

my response from Search API looks like this

```
{  
    "took":88,
    "timed_out":false,
    "_shards":{  
        "total":3,
        "successful":3,
        "failed":0
    },
    "hits":{  
        "total":2,
        "max_score":1.0,
        "hits":[  
            {  
                "_index":"myindex",
                "_type":"mytype",
                "_id":"first",
                "_score":1.0,
                "fields":{  
                    "name":[  "John Smith"  ]
                }
            },
            {  
                "_index":"myindex",
                "_type":"mytype",
                "_id":"second",
                "_score":1.0,
                "fields":{  
                    "name":[  "John Doe"  ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want the fields _index, _type and _score to be removed from each `hits.hits` element.
How do I do this?

Comment: How do you send your query?

Comment: @Val : via Search API (POST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) by specifying the `filter_path` parameter in the query string like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&fields=name&filter_path=hits.hits.fields' -d '{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "john"
        }
    }
}'
```

or using source filtering instead

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&_source=name&filter_path=hits.hits._source' -d '{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "john"
        }
    }
}'
```

Your response will look like this instead:

```
{  
    "hits":{  
        "hits":[  
            {  
                "fields":{  
                    "name":[  "John Smith"  ]
                }
            },
            {  
                "fields":{  
                    "name":[  "John Doe"  ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, the request URL loks like so POST http://<url>/myindex/mytype/_search?filterPath=hits.hits.fields&fields=name, but each hits element still has _index, _type and _score. btw, why does "name" automatically becomes array of string?

Comment: Are you sending the query via curl? Don't forget the single quotes around the whole URL

Comment: Ok, then please update your question with your client code so it's easier to see where the error lies.

Comment: hang on, this particular code is from someone else. I'm trying to recreate using another lib, so if it works with my code, then the problem is definitely with jest. I'm using AWS ES by the way, not sure if it has any effects, just an FYI

Comment: Just make sure to use `filter_path` and [not `filterPath`](https://github.com/aws-es-user/aws-es/blob/master/src/main/java/com/awses/main/ElasticSearchService.java#L22) and you'll be fine

Comment: got and additional question, there is any way to remove the hits object,  and just return the array?
Thanks!

Comment: @GerardoJaramillo You should ask another question since this is a different issue.

Comment: @musicsquad - Did you get the result you needed in the end and have just the array of indexes showing? Im facing the same issue and wanting to remove hits.hits from the response and also if possible _source without having to do a foreach loop on the client to remove this. Thanks

Comment: Just for reference for other people checking this,  that option is not available [if you are using version elasticsearch 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50506659/1280385).