# Need to return source fields only, without any metadata - how to use plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a requirement that we return just the source fields in search results, without any of the metadata.  From searching, I gather that this is not possible with elasticsearch, but I did find a reference to maybe using a plugin in this thread:

[Filter out metadata fields and only return source fields in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283033/filter-out-metadata-fields-and-only-return-source-fields-in-elasticsearch)

The plugin that was linked was this one:

https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-just-source/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/examples/justsource/rest/action/RestJustSourceAction.java

I'm still learning about elasticsearch, but can someone explain how I would implement and deploy that plugin in our elasticsearch configuration?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the first link you referenced, it is possible to do it with [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) which is not a plugin but a standard feature of ES:

```
GET /index/type/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

If you want to get rid of `hits.hits._source` you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/type/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source | jq '.hits.hits[]._source'
```

Comment: we know and have been trying with filter_path, but unfortunately, that still leaves some remnants like {"hits": {"hits": [   {"_source":  .  We want the response to be just the hits elements as an array.

Comment: That's a transformation you can do on the client side very easily or you can use `jq`

Comment: See my edited answer, which shows how to use `jq` to achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks for that and, actually when I was checking out your suggestion, I noticed that the 'actual' response from ES is straight string, so even using 'sed' does work also.  Cool :)!