# Remove or disable Elasticsearch default fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have a newbie question and I want to know that if we can remove default fields or not in elasticsearch

i mean :

```
"_index" : "iislogs",
 "_type" : "_doc",
 "_id" : "G2_plGwB4leTdasdfX",**
 "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" :{
      "S-Port" : "62416",
      "CS-Username" : "-",
      "CS-URI-Query" : "-"
```

if we have an index like that can we remove or disable default fields ? ( "_index , _type , _id , _score , and _source )

i want to get fields just like that :

```
      "S-Port" : "62416",
      "CS-Username" : "-",
      "CS-URI-Query" : "-"
```

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772834/need-to-return-source-fields-only-without-any-metadata-how-to-use-plugin/43774728#43774728

Comment: @Val thanks i tried this but did not worked for me. Btw i can disable them on kibana from (AdvancedSettings / MetaField) but it is not i am looking for

Comment: Can you explain what didn't work for you?

Comment: Oh i had a little typo with ' ' it worked. Thanks !